# backtrace_symbols gives me segfault

Tags: c++, gnu

Exception is defined here:

```
class MyException : public std::system_error {
  using std::system_error::system_error;
  public:
  const char* test () const throw () {
    void * array[30000];
    int nSize = backtrace(array, 30000);
    char ** symbols = backtrace_symbols(array, nSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < nSize; i++) {
      std::cout << symbols[i] << std::endl;

    }

    free(symbols);
  }
};
```

Thrown on bind when another process owns a port:

```
   if (errno = bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address)) < 0) {
          throw MyException(std::error_code(errno, std::generic_category()), "Bind failed");
        }
```

Caught here:

```
} catch (MyException& e) {
    std::cout << "Caught system_error with code " << e.code()
      << " meaning " << e.what() << e.test() << '\n';
  }
```

When e.test() is called there is a segmentation fault at the end of the stack trace. I believe it has to do with char** symbols and backtrace_symbols since commenting any code that deals with that will remove the backtrace. Am I using this function properly? What is the right way to do it?

Comment: The function doesn't return anything.

Comment: 30000 void-pointers is 240KB of stack-space -- possibly enough to overflow your thread's stack in some circumstances.  You might want to trim that down to a smaller number (e.g. 64), since in most cases it's only the first few entries that are of interest anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [tkausl points in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53136657/backtrace-symbols-gives-me-segfault#comment93166469_53136657), your function `test()` does not return anything.

```
  const char* test () const throw () {
    void * array[30000];
    int nSize = backtrace(array, 30000);
    char ** symbols = backtrace_symbols(array, nSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < nSize; i++) {
      std::cout << symbols[i] << std::endl;

    }

    free(symbols);
  }
```

Here you've told the compiler your function `test()` will return a `const char*`, but it in fact returns nothing. This is undefined behaviour:

> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; **this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function**

Turn your compiler warnings up to see a warning regarding this.